# Visual Studio 2013 does not detect Type Script "reference paths" when I start debugging in Internet Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript

I'm working through the examples listed at (http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-splitting-across-files) the website.

And my problem is to do with "reference paths" and "visual studio 2013" not detecting them.

And the Visual Studio 2013 debugger throws an error when I (press F5) attempt to debug the application.

The command line (command) "tsc --out app.js app.ts" works and the reference paths are detected and the result is a compiled single javascript file.

However Visual Studio 2013 does not compile the application.

Comment: What version of VS do you have? Update 1, 2, 3 or none?

Comment: VS version is "update 2"

Answer (score 1):

If you have Visual Studio 2013 and the TypeScript extension installed, right-click your project in the solution explorer and chose Properties. Click on the TypeScript Build tab. Select Combine JavaScript output into file: and type in a name to use for your combined file in the input field right next to the option. Remember you can use variables in this field. For example: "$(ProjectDir)dist\js\myCombinedFile.js".